# Can I use Git to track MP3 and AAC metadata without corrupting files?

Tags: git, mp3, aac, id3

I have a collection of roughly 7k (40GB) MP3 and AAC files, these files I have collected over the years and put through different players and organisers. Unfortunately during that time some of these applications alter the ID3 tags to add what it thinks the song is. One culprit is Apple Music which has destroyed the metadata I have collected and curated on my songs over a decode for many of my files.

Going forward I wanted to know whether using something like Git to track the files and any changes to them, would this work without corrupting the file?

Comment: Git could be used for tracking changes in files without corrupting the files. But it might be overkill for 40GB of music files.

Comment: In theory one can put thousands of files in git repo and if something is changing them get the info by running `git status ` . With the binary format files it makes little sense. Same if some external tool modifies hundreds or thousands of text files.

Comment: Have you begun implementing this and come upon some difficulties? That is the sort of question that is a better fit on this site. If you're just asking people's opinions on whether something is good/bad/etc, that is a better fit on a forum where open-ended discussion is the point.

Answer (score 0):

Git does not alter files in any way, as long as you don't use commands that could alter them, such as `git reset --hard` or `git rm file.mp3`. It tracks files by just comparing their metadata and indexing it.

It's perfectly safe, it might be not performing too well with data of that size though. And note that it'll track other changes, such as renames or other non-metadata media modifications, so you may not get accurate results.